# How to show unit count by type during game?

Tags: starcraft-2

Is it possible to show unit count by type during a game (i.e., # of SCVs, # of marines, etc.)?  I'm referring to something like the unit-count display that we can toggle when watching replays.  As a new player, it would be helpful to see this (for my own units only, obviously) during game in order to help get timing of builds correct.

For example, in Age of Empires II (the last RTS game i played, LOL), it was possible to show # of villagers by type (loggers/farmers/gold miners) at any given point in a game which made it quite easy to ensure adequate macro throughout the game.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no current way to see a full unit breakdown as a player during a game. You can see it as a spectator because it is built into the overlay that you gain access to when you are watching the game. This information makes it more engaging for the viewers.

However there are a few little tricks that may help when you are playing:

- When you are looking at your base (Nexus, Command Centre, Hatchery/Liar/Hive) you can see the current worker count as a total workers/max effective workers. For example 8/24 tells you that you have 8 total workers on that base. Add these numbers up with your other bases and you'll have a quick total. Refineries/Assimilators/Extractors also have a display of X/3 above them as well to aid in this counting.
- When selecting units you can select a certain type of unit by holding down the control key and clicking on the unit. It will then select all units of that type that are on the the current screen (it will not select units that are in another area of the map). The unit display at the bottom is 3 rows of 8 for a total of 24 units per page.
- Building on the above point, you can also use F2 to select all your army units (units that have an offensive capability that are not workers). This action will select all units, regardless of where they are on the map. Then with your entire army selected, you can again control click on one of the unit icons in the middle display area and it will only select that type of unit out of your entire army.

Answer (score 3):

Good news. You can check your worker count now! Just mouse over your supply in the top right corner of the screen, and it tells you how many workers you have vs how many army units.

As far as I know, there's no way to see a full breakdown of units by type in-game.